# Executing jQuery code after post success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a web application that uses Twitter bootstrap for a frontend framework and Laravel for a backend framework.

I have created a form that exists in a Twitter bootstrap modal (see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and I'm trying to utilize AJAX to submit the form data without leaving the page.

Right now, my form can do that utilizing this code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
   $('form[data-async]').on('submit', function (event) {
       var $form = $(this);
       var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));

   $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize(),

        success: function (data, status) {
            $target.html(data);
        },

        error: function () {
            alert("Please check your submission and try again.");
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

I'm trying to close the modal if the AJAX post is successful, but I can't seem to accomplish that. I tried using:

```
$('#createTicket').modal('hide');
```

but it causes the script to leave the page for some reason.

Would anyone know how to have the modal hide/toggle if there is a success? If you need more code, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Call the `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` methods on the `event` object you are passing into the form's submit handler:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

I really need to see your html to be certain. Try adding this attribute to your form tag.

```
<form onSubmit='return false;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used `event.preventDefault()` and also using `.moadl('hide')` method so it suppose to work but most probably you have `JavaScript` errors (check the browser console) so it's not working but you may use following approach and it should work:

```
$('form[data-async]').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));
    // Cache a reference of your modal form
    var createTicket = $('#createTicket');

    $.ajax({
        //...
        success:function(data){
            createTicket.modal('hide');
            // ...
        }
    });
});
```